# WAMP mysql connect another PC

Tags: mysql, wamp

any ide how to connect to my local mysql wamp server from another computer? Not in lan. For e.g. connect to 81.182.127.107, or see the phpmyadmin using 81.182.127.107phpmyadmin?

Comment: Just write:  `81.182.127.107/phpmyadmin` into the browser.

Comment: Sorry, i tried it, but its not works, for me. I try to solve it, but i cant, so i write here.

Comment: Can you access your server from the other computer? what if in command line: `ping 81.182.127.107`

Comment: reply from 81.182.127.107 ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect to a mysql server:

1. direct connection, eg. via database software or from your source code
2. via a local installed user interface, usually phpmyadmin which is a local hosted website.

mysql is bound to the local addresses by default. To change open the my.conf, and comment the bind-address: 127.0.0.1 like this:

```
#bind-address: 127.0.0.1
```

This will allow direct access to the mysql server from outside.

If you want to use phpmyadmin, you also need a webserver, which is apache by default at WAMP. There in the root web dir, phpmyadmin should be already installed, if not you need to install and configure it.

After this, http://ip-from-pc/phpmyadmin should bring you the user interface to your local mysql server.

Comment: i add this comment in my_config.h and restart the wamp and i cant connect to databese.. Why?

Comment: not in my_config.h, in the ini file. Under linux ist is the my.conf. On windows systems it should be something like Drive:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\my.ini

Comment: there aren't bind-address what i can set to comment :/

Comment: I´m sorry, i don´t work much with windows, this seems to be only in linux configuration. I´m still not clear about what you are trying to do. Maybe you can edit your original post to describe in more detail what you are planning to do.